# Run Stata from Python and assure that there was no errors

Tags: python, stata

I know how to start Stata from Python. Here I have small procedure

```py
def dostata(dofile, *params):
    ## Launch a do-file, given the fullpath to the do-file
    ## and a list of parameters.       
    cmd = ["C:\Program Files (x86)\Stata13\StataMP-64.exe", "do", dofile]
    for param in params:
        cmd.append(param)
    a = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)

path = "C:/My/do/file/dir/"
filename = "try.do"

dostata(path + filename, model, "1", "")
```

This is working, more or less. But it doesn't guarantee that the Stata program will finish successfully. How can I get some feedback from Stata to Python saying "Completed Successfully"?

Comment: I'm not yet very good with Python programming so I can't say for sure. If its not possible, I would suggest writing the Stata output to a plain text log file, then scanning that document in Python for errors or return codes. You could use regex for this and search for r([0-9]); or something similar in order to find if the Stata output contains errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subprocess uses `returncode` to return *success* (zero) or *failed*  (non-zero) result of the underlying called process.

However, Stata do files are not exactly executables but run as [batch jobs](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/windows/batch-mode/). For this reason, Stata.exe will always return a success code as it will always run regardless of `.do` code output. Therefore, consider the below where Python reads and outputs Stata's log to its console for user to see code result. Possibly even condition Python to scan log file for any [Stata error code](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/perror.pdf), `r(1)` - `r(9999)`, and if present in log file force Python to message it.

```
import os, subprocess

# CURRENT DIRECTORY
cd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

def openlog(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as txt:
        for line in txt:
            print(line.strip())

def dostata(dofile, logfile, *params):
    ## Launch a do-file, given the fullpath to the do-file
    ## and a list of parameters.       
   cmd = ["C:\Program Files (x86)\Stata13\StataMP-64.exe", "/b", "do", dofile]
   for param in params:
       cmd.append(param)
   a = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)

   print('STATA OUTPUT:\n')
   openlog(os.path.join(cd, logfile))


path = "C:/My/do/file/dir/"
filename = "try.do"
logname = "try.log"

result = dostata(os.path.join(path, filename), logname, "")
```

Comment: The problem is that if error happens while running Stata do file and getting error within do file, Python still runs and waits for response until one closes Stata, and than no error is generated, because application Stata finished as expected.

Comment: Did you test this? Python should return output exactly as Stata's console displays and if Stata ends execution due to error, so will this Python subprocess. Of course if you have other .py code after this subprocess, code will continue unless you exit script: `sys.exit(1)`.

Comment: I tried couple of times. Stata error of non existing file was not captured.

Comment: Turns out Stata .do files are not exactly executables but are run as batch jobs in command line. I had thought it was interchangeable with Rscript.exe to run R scripts as I have done with Python. But using `/b` argument you can have a log outputted (same name as .do file but in current directory of .py script) and have Python read it into console. See my code edit and text explanation of options to scan log file for error.