# Calling Stata with subprocess.call() finishes the job too soon

Tags: python, subprocess, stata

I am using subprocess.call() to call stata processes and pipe the log output to the console. The code I use for calling Stata is as follows, slightly modified from
[Run Stata from Python and assure that there was no errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33807324/run-stata-from-python-and-assure-that-there-was-no-error)

```
def openlog(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as txt:
        for line in txt:
            print(line.strip())

def dostata(dofile, logfile, *params):
    ## Launch a do-file, given the fullpath to the do-file
    ## and a list of parameters.       
    cmd = [stata_path, "-e", "do", dofile]
    for param in params:
        cmd.append(param)
    a = subprocess.Popen(cmd, cwd = os.getcwd())
    a.wait() ##Wait for the process to finish???

    print('STATA OUTPUT:\n')
    openlog(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), logfile))

dofile = 'PATH'
logfile = 'PATH'

result = dostata(dofile, logfile, '')
```

This is a Stata code which imports a 50GB .csv file right after opening the log. If I run it from Stata, it works, it loads the .csv file (Takes a while) and does what it has to do. However, if I run it with this command, what happens is that it takes two seconds, and this log comes out:

```
STATA OUTPUT:

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
name:  <unnamed>
log:  D:\thesis_suburb\code_replication/4_pixel_database/agg_sprawl.log
log type:  text
opened on:  27 Sep 2022, 17:09:35

.
.
. import delimited "data\regression_tables\pixel_database.csv"
(encoding automatically selected: ISO-8859-1)
```

So aparently the primary Stata process that I open dies right after starting the reading-in of the CSV file, and then nothing else happens. Stata must be spawning some other processes which continue the work, but I have no way of latching on to those? What should I do here? This is the way that everybody tells me to launch Stata from a script, but it clearly is not working...

Comment: Sounds more like the process *did* finish, but it started other processes you didn't wait for.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @user2357112 yes, but if Stata is spawning other processes, say, when it imports the file, how do I force Python to wait until these children processes are also done?